# How to add PathVariable to DefaultSuccessUrl in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In Spring Security Config I have the next method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
           .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
               .and()   
        .formLogin()
           .loginPage("/login")
           .defaultSuccessUrl("/profile") // <-- here
               .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Can I somehow redirect to URL `/profile/{user_id}` after successful login?

Now it redirects to URL `/profile`. I will be thankful for any advice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi, you can to try something like this:**

**1.** Create a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler where you will extract it from Authentication->Principal(what is usually jwt token where you have user_id) -> you can convert it into an object for more flexibility work and you can pass your user_id into MDC what is ThreadLocal.
[image]

**2.** Create a bean of AuthenticationSuccessHandler in your SecurityConfig  class
[image]

**3.** Finally you can extract it from MDC(threadLocal)

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/profile/" + MDC.get("user_id"))
```

P.S. Just give me a feedback if it was helpfully